# Git blame lines matching string on multiple files

Tags: git

Here's the git challenge of the day. I've spent a good hour on it but someone probably knows it off the top of their head.

How would you do a git blame on all the *_template.html files in the repo and only print out lines that have the string "foobar" in them?

I'm looking for the first occurrence of that string so if there's another way to get the last modified date on those lines then that would work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the hack I came up with...

```
git ls-files -- '**/*_template.html' | xargs -I{} git blame {} | grep "foobar"
```

Comment: Let's hope he/she doesn't happen to have a person called "foobar" committing to the repo ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton - I am impressed :D ! Note you can add -f to the git blame command, e.g. `git blame -f {}` to get the filename listed as well

Answer (score 2):

You should use `git log -p -Sfoobar`. This will print commit diffs which have either introduced `foobar`, or completely removed `foobar` from your repository. It will not print any commits that had `foobar` already.

This is extremely useful to find out why given symbol was added or removed.

You can also limit this to some files or directories: `git log -Sfoobar *_template.html`

Comment: having trouble getting this to work. the actual "foobar" string is a bit more complicated (special characters I need to escape - !:<> etc). any help on that?

Comment: Just enclose string in double quotes: `git log -S"string_to_escape"` - it works

Comment: error "-bash: !foobar: event not found" (even enclosed in the double quotes)

Comment: Hmm. I tested that only single quotes work for `!`. E.g. `git log -S"<!--"` does not work, but `git log -S'<!--'` does.

Comment: This answer has full explanation how bash escaping works for `!`: http://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark